# AngularJS RESTful over SSL

Tags: rest, angularjs, ssl

I have a problem with RESTful service call over SSL in AngularJS application, it is a POST call.
In Chrome's inspector I can see OPTION call where column status has value Canceled and column Type has value Pending.

At a server side I get error: 
default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7, fatal error: 80: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?

If I execute a POST request from Chrome's plugin Poster it works fine. Also, it works fine if I turn off ssl and use http insteadof https.
It also works if I create html page with submit to https url.

Thanks for any idea.

Zlaja

Answer (score 2):

is it trying to do a POST cross-origin?

A POST to the same origin should not result in an OPTIONS pre-flight query.  So it sounds like you may be having an issue that the OPTIONS query isn't returning the correct headers.

This would also be a reason why Chrome's Poster plugin works fine because it's a plugin and specifically bypasses the usual Cross-origin security protection for debugging purposes.

Have a look at cross origin (CORS) information here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: This is OPTIONS headers: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*"
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, X-Response-Time, X-PINGOTHER, X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With"
"Access-Control-Request-Headers": "*"
"Access-Control-Request-Method": "*". If I use http insteadof https, it works fine.

Comment: You sir, deserve 1 million internets... We recently purchased and enabled SSL certificates across our web domains and didn't understand why the backend servers stopped serving content across multiple domains. Until you mentioned CORS that is... make sure that your backend is configured to allow requests from other domains!